# Reactive Form Control not working on boolean because value is not being updated

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to validate a group of checkboxes so that they only validate if all four are selected. What is happening is that the 'this.dataService.minRequired' variable is updating in the service, however the validation state does not seem to change.  I moved it to my service thinking that it would fix this issue however I had the same problem when the variable was in my controller.

The type of checkbox I'm using doesn't have a 'checked' value or any other way of accessing the state of the checkbox, hence all the workarounds. I can't abandon them so am seeking a solution within these confines.

**card.component.html:**

```
<xyz-checkbox-group orientation="vertical" ngDefaultControl [formControl]="newCardForm.get('eligibility')">
                    <div style="float: left; width: 45%;">
                            <xyz-checkbox ngDefaultControl [(checked)]="checkedFlag1" id="checkbox1" (change)="checker()">Account is Open and in Good Standing</xyz-checkbox>
                            <xyz-checkbox ngDefaultControl [(checked)]="checkedFlag2" id="checkbox2" (change)="checker()">Balance Less Than 30 Days Past Due</xyz-checkbox>
                            <xyz-checkbox ngDefaultControl [(checked)]="checkedFlag3" id="checkbox3" (change)="checker()">Annual Income - $200,000.00 (minimum)</xyz-checkbox>
                            <xyz-checkbox ngDefaultControl [(checked)]="checkedFlag4" id="checkbox4" (change)="checker()">Current Card Limit - $5,000.00</xyz-checkbox>
                        <display-error *ngIf="(submitted && newCardForm.get('eligibility').invalid) || (submitted && newCardForm.get('eligibility').invalid && newCardForm.get('eligibility').dirty)  || (submitted && newCardForm.errors.checks)" 
                        error="Only 'Client is a Student' is optional." class="alertLabel"></display-error>
```

**card.component.ts:**

```
  checkedFlag1: boolean;
  checkedFlag2: boolean;
  checkedFlag3: boolean;
  checkedFlag4: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.forms = new FormArray([
      this.accountDetailsForm = new FormGroup({
        productGroup: new FormControl('', {validators: Validators.required}),
      }), 
      this.newCardForm = new FormGroup({
        address: new FormControl('', {validators: Validators.required}),
        eligibility: new FormControl('', {validators: Validators.required})
        }, this.validateCheckboxes(this.dataService.minRequired)),
      ]);
  }

  public checker(){
    let checked = 0;
    this.checkboxArray = [];
    this.checkboxArray.push(
      this.checkedFlag1, this.checkedFlag2, this.checkedFlag3, this.checkedFlag4
    )

    for(let i  = 0; i < this.checkboxArray.length; i++){
      if(this.checkboxArray[i] == true){
        checked++; 
      }
    }

    if (checked == 4) {
      this.dataService.minRequired = true;
    } else {
      this.dataService.minRequired = false;
    }
  }

  public validateCheckboxes(boolean): ValidatorFn{
    return function validate (formGroup: FormGroup){

      console.log("entered with: " + boolean)
      if(!boolean){
        return {
          checks: true
        };
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is checkedFlag 5/6/7 for?

Comment: When you say that minValue doesn't update in the form, do you mean that you are trying to display the result of minValue somewhere in your template?  Can you explain a bit what you mean by this?

Comment: Checked 5/6/7 are from my code but I was omitting them to keep the post succinct, I just missed a few. Updated now.

Comment: The minRequired variable works like its supposed to everywhere except in the form validation. It stays at false no matter what (the console.log for the boolean in validateCheckboxes says it is false even though it says true outside of validation). It just remains at its initial value within the form.

Comment: The 'minRequired' variable is scoped within a service.  So I don't understand what you mean by "within the form".  Are you saying that the value is being set correctly in the service, but that the validation logic is not reacting to the changed value?

Comment: Pretty much. I moved it to the service but I originally had it wtihin the same component and had the same issue.

Comment: See my answer below - I believe it's because the minRequired value is not updating dynamically within the validator function because it is evaluated once when the function is constructed,  not dynamically as your application state changes.  You should try to use the async validator function with an observable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument being passed is created when the function is created not reactive to your service state.  When you enter the validation function, it's the equivalent of

```
this.validateCheckboxes(false)
```

You want to write an async function that returns an observable.  You can then change your minRequired into an observable that emits "true" when the right conditions are met, which you then merge into the async validator to raise an error or call true based on present state.

More information can be found in the custom validators section of the angular docs: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Comment: Thanks, this set me on the right path so I was able to find a solution. I ended up using BehaviorSubject based on this reddit comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/76inse/noob_observable_on_change_of_value/ 

An Observable probably would've worked too but the logic is in place for one boolean, this made the most sense for me.